# Using norm function in matlab on a subvector of a 3D vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, norm

I've a vector called x that is a 3D vector.
In my code I need to compute the norm of x(1,1,:) (the vector composed by x(1,1,1), x(1,1,2),...). If I try to use the norm(x(1,i,:)) command, Matlab returns me the error "Input must be 2-D". What can I do?

Comment: Why x(1,1,:) is not seen as an array?

Comment: You can apply `squeeze` to make the vector two-dimensional: `norm(squeeze(x(2,3,:)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB’s `norm` is a “special” function, it doesn’t work like many other functions such as `sum` and `mean`.

However, [`vecnorm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vecnorm.html) does behave like those functions. It computes the norm along the first non-singleton dimension, or you can specify along which dimension to compute the norm:

```
vecnorm(x(1,1,:))
vecnorm(x,2,3) % computes 2-norm for all vectors along 3rd dimension.
```

Note that this function was introduced in R2017b. For older versions you can emulate the behavior using `sqrt(sum(x.^2,3))`.